# How to access content from secured website via proxy tunnel without authentication required

Tags: proxy, web-scraping, http-proxy, tunnel, tunneling

I would like to scrape / download contend from site which requires authentication. To do so, I need some tunnel between my CLI / Node.js app and the secured website without any authentication. Please see the schema:

`Scraper / downloader app -> [no passowrd] -> some proxy -> user (login) -> secured website with login / authentication`

Any idea how to make it so?

Comment: What kind of authentication does the secured website accept?

Comment: How can I find out that?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how exactly the target site handles authentication, your problem could be fixed by setting a simple [`node-http-proxy`](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) app.

This might be the solution (copy-pasted from the documentation, and modified):

```
var http = require('http'),
httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  // Your mileage may vary here.
  req.setHeader("Authentication", "Basic mysecrettoken=");
  proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://127.0.0.1:5060' });
});

server.listen(5050);
```

See https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy for more information.